# Can we fully customize the Front without being stuck with Microsoft layout habits?

Tags: css, custom-masterpage, custom, html, front-end

I'm going to be the Tech Lead for a new project targeted 200 company's high people.

The main aspect is to favor UI/UX.
Indeed, the targeted audience is about 60 years old and expect a very high-level of simplicity "à la Apple".

I never used SharePoint in the past.
In the 2016 version, is it possible to fully customize the front-end? By fully, I mean really every item and every part.